# How do you access an allocated array's elements within shared memory

Tags: c++, arrays, shared-memory

I am extremely new to using shmget or any of the 'V' libraries for C and by extension, C++. I think I got the gist of the allocation of shared memory, and how to get a pointer to it, but when I try to access a specific index of my shared-memory array, I get a seg fault. Did I allocate the array incorrectly, or am I accessing the element incorrectly? Any help is greatly apprecited.

EDIT: I have gotten the segfaults to stop by adding the characters 7540| in front of IPC_CREAT. While this solves my problem in the short run, I really need to understand why this fixed it. I understand that IPC_CREAT creates a segment rather than trying to access it when in shmget, but why did the addition of 7540| to the front of IPC_CREAT fix the segfault on access??

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int shmid;
    int *array;
    int elements = 10;
    key_t key = 1234;

    shmid = shmget(key, elements*sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT);

    array = (static_cast<int *>(shmat(shmid, 0, 0)));

    cout<<"Memory allocated" <<endl;

    //Seg fault here
    array[0] = 1;

    shmdt((void *) array);

    cout<<"Memory deallocated" <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or intersections between the two languages. Test the return values of functions for errors.

Comment: Check if your shmid is -1.  If it is, print errno

Comment: See the man page; "In addition to the above flags, the least significant 9 bits of shmflg  specify  the
       permissions  granted to the owner, group, and others.  These bits have the same for‐
       mat, and the same meaning, as the mode argument of open(2)."  So without this, you create the segment with permissions 000, i.e. no permissions, and `shmat` fails for lack of permission (which you don't notice because you didn't check the return value).

Comment: 7450 probably happens to have enough bits set that it happens to work, but `0600` (octal) would have been a more sensible permission value to OR with.

Comment: noted. I saw the flags listed but didn't actually connect that they corresponded to a permission system for the memory segment, so I just set 7540 due to not understanding why seemingly piping an int would change the outcome at all.

Comment: You do know that `|` is the bitwise OR operator, right?

Comment: Yes, bad translation of what I meant, I was just trying to name the pipe itself, not imply that the number was being piped into the macro